# Can "Microsoft Connector for Oracle by Attunity" be used as Provider for Linked Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, oracle11g

I have heard that the Microsoft Connector for Oracle by Attunity to be used by SSIS is more efficient than MSDAOra or OraOledb.Oracle drivers.

Can "Oracle by Attunity" be used as a provider for a linked server?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't try it and find out?